# how to give css for following data

Tags: html, css

how to give css for getting the page as follows in the same div. am having the data in the following way with more sub parts as in the second phase.

```
                                              abcde
                       a production           productions
                                              limited 
   total
                                              jackson 
                       b productions          productions
                                              limited
```

the code am using is as follwos.

css

```
.label_left21 {
width: 20%;
float: left;
text-align:center;
line-height: 30px;
    margin:0 10px 0 0;

    word-wrap:break-word;

   }
.text_right22 {
width: 20%;
float:left;
text-align:center;

}
.text_right23 {
width: 55%;
float:left;

}
```

html as

```
<div class="label_left21"><br><br><br><label>BUDGET</label></div>
<div class="text_right22"><br><br><br><label>PUBLIC</label></div>
<div class="text_right23"><label>State</label></div> 
<div class="text_right22"><br><br><br><label>PRIVATE</label></div>
<div class="text_right23"><br><label>publication</label></div>
```

but it is not working the data is clashing if there are more sub parts

Comment: It would be easier to use a table with `rowspan` attributes on the cells

Comment: can you give some sample coding please

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/fwv97/

Comment: thanks kovala its amazing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it would be easier if you use tables with rowspan ..and css can be used to adjust the width and margins of the cells  here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<table >

<tr>
  <td rowspan="9">total</td>

</tr>
<tr>
  <td rowspan="4">a production</td>


</tr>

<tr>
<td>abcde</td>


</tr>
<tr>
<td>productions</td>


</tr>
<tr>
<td>limited</td>


</tr>

<tr>
  <td rowspan="4">a production</td>


</tr>
<tr>
<td>jackson</td>


</tr>

<tr>
<td>productions</td>


</tr>
<tr>
<td>limited</td>


</tr>


</table>


</body>
</html>
```

[image: output]

Comment: thanks a lot. in between i too found. i have one more doubt that how to give colspan that is i need to get total in two columns and the data jackson productions limited in next column.